# Why does updating a model trigger rails to load other models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a weird behavior on my project. If I update/save a record on my `::Product` model, rails always load up other models relates to it.

this:

```
p = Product.first
p.update(name: 'whatever')
```

will output this:

```
 (1.2ms)  BEGIN
  Product::Brand Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  `product_brands`.* FROM `product_brands` WHERE `product_brands`.`id` = 24 LIMIT 1
  Product::Condition Load (5.4ms)  SELECT  `product_conditions`.* FROM `product_conditions` WHERE `product_conditions`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Product::Category Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  `product_categories`.* FROM `product_categories` WHERE `product_categories`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Product Update (4.0ms)  UPDATE `products` SET `updated_at` = '2021-01-28 21:10:16', `name` = 'whatever' WHERE `products`.`id` = 1
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
```

`product` belongs to `:brand`, `:condition`, and `:category`, but it also belongs to other models as well, but only these three models got triggered.

Any idea why this happened?

**EDIT**
I didn't set any custom validation in the Product class. Nor does scope or default_scope.

**EDIT 2**
I just realised something. It doesn't only happen in my Product model. But ALL models that have `belongs_to :something` relationship will trigger the same queries, unless I add `optional: true`. Is it an intended behavior for Rails? Can I prevent this without adding `optional: true` to the belongs_to relation?

Comment: Might be triggered by your validations, `before_save` callback and such.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code from the Product model? Validations, scopes, callbacks, basically everything except methods. Most probably you have something that causes the eager loading there. The most obvious would be:

`has_many :brands, :include => true`

`include :brands`

`default_scope includes(:brands)`

Also as Sergio pointed out, many callbacks and validations can load these related models to perform some actions.

Comment: I don't have any validation in the Product model (not that I set anyway). Does rail provide default validation? I edited my question. This behavior apparently happens to all models that have non-optional `belongs_to` relationships